# Adding a sliderInput to a ggplot line chart in ShinyDashboard

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I've been struggling to add a functional slider input to my ggplot line chart for "number of observations", but I keep getting errors .. The code below works but the plot does not change ( I tried lots of stuff like adding a **reactive** function or adding **input$obs** inside ggplot but it still didn't work) .. I really appreciate your help ! Thanks

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(dashboardthemes)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

df=read_excel("MASI.xlsx")

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram


ui <- dashboardPage(
    
    dashboardHeader(title = "Finance Dashboard"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(

        
        # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
        fluidRow(
 
        
        box(
            title = "Line chart", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
            collapsible = TRUE,
            plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)
        ),
        
        box(
            title = "MASI", status = "primary",  solidHeader = TRUE,
            "The MASI index (Moroccan All Shares Index) is a stock index that tracks the performance of all 
                companies listed in the Casablanca Stock Exchange located at Casablanca."
        ),
        
        box(
            title = "Inputs", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,  collapsible = TRUE,
            sliderInput("obs",
                        "Number of observations:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = length(df$MASI),
                        value = 50)
            
            
            
        ),
        
        ),
    ),
    setBackgroundColor(
        color = "white",
        gradient = c("linear", "radial"),
        direction = c("bottom", "top", "right", "left"),
        shinydashboard = TRUE
    )
)



server <- function(input, output) {
    

    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
       ggplot(df,aes(x=Session, y=MASI)) + geom_line( color="darkblue", size=0.7) + theme_bw()
    }, bg="transparent")
    

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**EDIT**

Thank you for the kind answer **@chemdork123**.

I want to add a Date range in addition to the sliderInput. Here's what I did:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(dashboardthemes)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

df=read_excel("MASI.xlsx")

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram

box_height = "20em"
plot_height = "16em"

ui <- dashboardPage(
    
    dashboardHeader(title = "Finance Dashboard"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(

        
        # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
        fluidRow(
 
        
        box(
            title = "Line chart", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
            collapsible = TRUE,
            plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)
        ),
        
        box(
            title = "MASI", status = "primary",  solidHeader = TRUE,
            "The MASI index (Moroccan All Shares Index) is a stock index that tracks the performance of all 
                companies listed in the Casablanca Stock Exchange located at Casablanca."
        ),
        
        box(
            title = "Inputs", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,  collapsible = TRUE,
            
            sliderInput("obs",
                        "Number of observations:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = length(df$MASI),
                        value = 50),
            
            dateRangeInput("date", strong("Date range"),
                           start = "2015-01-02", end = "2020-07-17",
                           min = "2015-01-02", max = "2020-07-17")
        ),
        
        
        box(
            title = "Line chart", status = "success", solidHeader = TRUE,
            collapsible = TRUE,
            plotOutput("plot2", height = 250)
        ),
        
        box(
            title = "Return", status = "success",  solidHeader = TRUE,
            "The relative difference of the MASI index"
        ),
        
        box(
            title = "Inputs", status = "success", solidHeader = TRUE,  collapsible = TRUE,
            sliderInput("obs",
                        "Number of observations:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = length(df$MASI),
                        value = 50)
        ),
        
        
        ),
    ),
    setBackgroundColor(
        color = "white",
        gradient = c("linear", "radial"),
        direction = c("bottom", "top", "right", "left"),
        shinydashboard = TRUE
    )
)



server <- function(input, output) {
    
    reactive_data <- reactive({
        set.seed(8675309)  # for some consistent sampling
        
        df <- df[sample(x=1:nrow(df), size = input$obs),]
        return(df)
        
        req(input$date)
        validate(need(!is.na(input$date[1]) & !is.na(input$date[2]), "Error: Please provide both a start and an end date."))
        validate(need(input$date[1] < input$date[2], "Error: Start date should be earlier than end date."))
        df %>%
            filter(
                date > as.POSIXct(input$date[1]) & date < as.POSIXct(input$date[2]
                ))
        
    })

    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
       ggplot(reactive_data(),aes(x=Session, y=MASI)) + geom_line(color="darkblue", size=0.7) + theme_bw()
    }, bg="transparent")

    
    
    output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(df,aes(x=Session, y=Return)) + geom_line( color="darkblue", size=0.7) + theme_bw()
    }, bg="transparent")

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is a link for the [Dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qb5oX5BsDg9n_5GoJ-QfjtD2VWlIOshp/view?usp=sharing)

[Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXzhP.png)

Comment: You will need to reference `input$obs` somewhere within the `server` part of the app... It's not referenced at all in the code you show - how are you intending to use it to modify the plot?

Comment: @chemdork123 That's the problem, I tried referencing it in many ways but it didn't work .. I could do it for a hitstogram like `geom_hist(bins=input$obs)`, but  I can't seem to get it to work on a line chart .. for example I tired adding `geom_line(bins=input$obs)` and `geom_line(input$obs)` .. etc. Thank you for your reply

Comment: Well, considering the value of `input$obs` will be a number, this should make sense.  Neither `geom_line(bins=input$obs)` nor `geom_line(input$obs)` would work, since something like `geom_line(bins=50)` nor `geom_line(50)` would work either.  If you're looking to bin your data, you'd have to do that in a separate reactive method that was called in your server.  Something like:  `server... data_prep <- reactive({...})` then also in the server include your `renderPlot({   ggplot( data_prep(), aes(....`.

Comment: @chemdork123 Hey man .. I really can't figure this out, I tried what you suggested for ex :   ```reactive_data <- reactive({
        req(input$obs)
        df %>% filter(obs == input$obs) })```
    
    ```output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
       ggplot(reactive_data(),aes(x=Session, y=MASI)) + geom_line( color="darkblue", size=0.7) + theme_bw()
    }, bg="transparent")``` .. Really appreciate your aid, I've never been this stuck before

Comment: I'll help you out with an example that works using `mtcars` to show you the general approach.

Answer (score 1):

OP.  Without your data, it's difficult to give you a clear answer to your particular question, but I can show you how the `input$obs` slider input control can be used (or any other one for that matter) to filter and provide data for your `ggplot()` function to display.

Here's a working app that gives you two controls to adjust what data is displayed from the `mtcars` built-in dataset.  The `sliderInput()` control determines how many rows are sampled from the total `mtcars` dataset.  The `selectInput()` control allows you to select one or all of the values for `mtcars$carb` to display in the chart based on the sampled dataset.

You will see the general approach on how to use both inputs reactively is to create a reactive function (called `sample_cars()`) that is called inside of the `renderPlot()` function.  The reactive function `sample_cars()` returns a data frame that is used in the `ggplot()` call.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  dashboardHeader(title = "Example App"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
  
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      box(
        title = "Line chart", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
        collapsible = TRUE,
        plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
      box(
        title = "Inputs", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,  collapsible = TRUE,
        sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",
          min = 1, step = 1, max = nrow(mtcars), value = nrow(mtcars)),
        selectInput("carbs", "Select carb to show",
          choices = c('All', unique(mtcars$carb))
        )
      ),
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  sample_cars <- reactive({
    set.seed(8675309)  # for some consistent sampling
    df <- mtcars[sample(x=1:nrow(mtcars), size = input$obs),]
    if(input$carbs != "All")
      df <- df %>% dplyr::filter(carb == input$carbs)
    return(df)
  })
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(sample_cars(), aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point() +
      labs(title=paste('You selected',input$obs, 'cars\n and to show',input$carbs, 'values of carb!'))
  }, bg="transparent")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Man :) Thank you very much, your kind answer was all I needed to understand how the reactive function works and get the code to work .. Just one more question about **Date range** if possible .. I'll post it in an edit above. Thank you very much .. I really appreciate your help